# Haskell records setter export

Tags: haskell

Is there any way to export record "getter" but not "setter"?

Example.
Assume we have `M1.hs`

```
module M1(customCtor, field1) where
  data DType = DCtor { field1 :: Int }
  customCtor = DCtor { field1 = 1 }
```

and `M2.hs`

```
import M1
modified = customCtor{ field1 = 3 }  -- how to prevent this?
main = putStrLn . show . field1 $ modified
```

I fould like to be able run `field1` getter in M2.hs but not to update record outside of M1.
If it is possible, could you point me to relevant part of Haskell documentation?
If it is not, can you explain why?

Comment: You have no control over exporting or importing record names, because Haskell's record system is hackish at best. The closest you can get is probably using lenses, which happen to be *much* better than records.

Comment: @Rhymoid is it too much to ask to show how my example would look with lenses? Do I ditch record style data completely with them? Or do I just export accessor functions provided by lenses like synonims, described in answer below? Sorry if it doesn't make sense, I have no idea how it would look with lenses...

Comment: Must've had a brainfart. This isn't easier with lenses >_< Neil Brown's solution is much closer to something useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One fairly easy option is to define a synonym and export that:

```
module M1(customCtor, getField1) where

data DType = DCtor { field1 :: Int }
customCtor = DCtor { field1 = 1 }

getField1 = field1
```

Here, `getField1` is a "getter" function (type: `DType -> Int`) that gets `field1` but doesn't have the additional status of being a record field for updates.

Comment: And export the type constructor

Comment: @jozefg. My example compiles and works without exporting type constructor. As far as I understand exporting `DType` allows users of M1 include it in their type signatures. So if I don't export it they can only put type variables in place of `DType` in their signatures or rely on type inference. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The export list should read `module M1(DType, customCtor, getField1)`. This exports the type `DType`, but not its constructors or its fields. If `DType` is omitted from the export list, you can't use `DType`'s name outside of the module.